# want to draw a list of polygons and detect which polygon was selected

Tags: iphone, ios, polygon, uibezierpath

I am drawing a polygon using the `UIBezierPath` class.

I have list of polygons. Now when I click any polygon I want to detect which polygon it is. 
I think same concept you can see in `UIMapView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGPoint p = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

   // UIBezierPath *pathTodetect; Path of the shape that you want to detect. In a for loop you can check for all possible paths. 

    if(CGPathContainsPoint(pathTodetect.CGPath,nil, p, NO))
    {    

        NSLog(@"touched.");
        // the touch is inside the shape  
    }   

}
```

Comment: thans a lot, its working fine. i am working it from last 2 days. i want this code from last 2 days.  but one things is wrong. we have to write pathTodetect.CGPath there.

Comment: I too wondering for the same thing from last two days thanks a lot for both of u

Comment: @HeartPAL,krishna Glad to help you. It should be pathTodetect.CGPath I will update it. Thanks.